# Ionic Accordion List Differentiated

Tags: ionic-framework, accordion

I'm trying to create a list with subcategories (in 3 levels) with some particularities, i need to make the accordion to only open when clicked on the icon, and if click in the content of accordion (the title), open a link..

I found a very nice model on the internet with 2 levels that we can see here:

http://codepen.io/drr/pen/emxoaL

```
<ion-content>

  <ion-list>
    <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
      <ion-item class="item-stable"
                ng-click="toggleGroup(group)"
                ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
          <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
        &nbsp;
        Group {{group.name}}
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="item-accordion"
                ng-repeat="item in group.items"
                ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
        {{item.subId}}
      </ion-item>
    </div>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Someone can help me to implement the third level, and help-me to make this particularities?

Comment: I found this exemple with 3 levels, but don't have the effect slowly when click to open the accordion, and, how ever, don't have the particularities (to open the accordion only when click in the icon, and in the title open a link).
http://codepen.io/morsiki/pen/KdMRgN?editors=101